# How to configure Swiftmailer in order to send correct mutations

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

Following code...

```
$umlaute = array("&uuml;", "&ouml;", "&uuml;", "&Auml;", "&Ouml;", "&Uuml;", "&szlig;");
$ersetzen = array("ü", "ö", "ü", "Ä", "Ö", "Ü", "ß");
$model->bodytext = str_replace($umlaute, $ersetzen, $model->bodytext);
$model->save();
```

will save record into database like this:

```
Ihre Bewerbung haben wir erhalten. Vielen Dank für Ihr Interesse!Aktuell können ....
```

I noticed, that mail being sent using Swiftmailer will be like this:

```html
Message-ID: <341358d8a98f625c151345ce9457be1c@localhost>
Date: Mon, 12 Mar 2018 21:57:29 +0100
Subject: Absage
From: maximilianK.mitarbeiter@gmx.net
To: goetz.bewerber@gmx.net
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Ihre Bewerbung haben wir erhalten. Vielen Dank f=C3=BCr Ihr Interesse!Aktuell k=C3=B6nnen...
```

As U can see, this is grave difference. Any ideas, how to configure Swiftmailer in order to send mail according german mutation  respectively record in database?

P.S.: This is how I am sending Mail:

```html
 if ($model->gesendet == 1 && !$multiple) {
                    $SendObject = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()->setFrom($string)
                            ->setTo($model->mail_antwortadresse)
                            ->setSubject($model->betreff)
                            ->setTextBody($model->bodytext)
                            ->send();
                    $session->addFlash("info", "Die Mail wurde ohne Anhänge versandt.Bitte überprüfen sie ihren Maileingang");
```

Comment: what is your default charset for the column, and the database conenction?

Comment: i just sent an email using hardcoded text above that is in german i think, and it just sent the mail in proper encoding you can try setting the charset using `->setCharset('utf-8')` although it is default for the swiftmailer, otherwise i would suggest you to save the text in original encoding in the database rather than converting it on runtime , change charset for your column to `utf8mb4` and connection to `utf-8`